# Multiple IF statements to make a true statement?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my Google Spreadsheet, I have multiple dropdown menus that if they all say Qualify, Too Close to Call, Priority or Wall to Wall I would like for it to spit out my true statement. I can't get it to tell me either my true or false statement. The code is in column H2

```
=if(E2="Qualifies","Write Offer Now", OR(E2="Too Close to Call","Write Offer Now",And(F2=Yes,"Write Offer Now",OR(F2=Priority,"Write Offer Now",And(G2="Qualifies","Write Offer Now", OR(G2="Wall to Wall","Write Offer Now",""))))))
```

Comment: Let me try and rephrase. I want a cell to read true only if three other separate cells say true. Problem is when one column is true even when the other two cells say false I get a true value. How do I make Google sheets say true only when all the values are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want a cell to read true only if three other separate cells say
>   true. Problem is when one column is true even when the other two cells
>   say false I get a true value. How do I make Google sheets say true
>   only when all the values are true

```
=IF(AND(E2=TRUE, F2=TRUE, G2=TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)
```